# What is this resistor?

Tags: resistors

I am trying to find the value of a blown resistor so that I may replace it.
Its from a Circulation Booster V3 circuit board.
The marking on the board where the resistor lives is marked L1
It is green and can be seen in place and burned out in picture 1.
It is in close-up in picture 2.

[image: circuit board]

[image: resister]

Comment: That's not a resistor, that's an inductor, hence the marking _L_ 1. Is there any possibility you can see the colours of the rings? They contain a code which indicates the value.

Comment: I would be concerned as to what the root cause of this fault is: the damage to that inductor is fairly catastrophic, and it could well be that it is not the only component to have failed.

Comment: What the hell is a "Circulation Booster V3"? ~~~ Edit: It's a quack medical appliance. You're not going to be able to fix it. You might be able to make it behave as it did from the factory, but it still won't work.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson is correct but too optimistic. There is approximately zero chance that replacing that part will restore whatever functionality it originally had.

Comment: Looking at that board it looks like a few other areas have some indications of excessive heat, the brown areas are what I am talking about. You may have a lot more damage there then you think.

Comment: @ConnorWolf which part of it is 'quack'? Running small currents through muscles makes them twitch ( Galvanism ), and muscles which are active have increased circulation, so it seems to be sound.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: If a circuit's function is to inject noticeable amounts of current to electrodes that are attached to a person, I would be disinclined to attempt any repairs.  In competently-designed device, hazardous conditions will not exist absent a very improbable combination of failures.  Given that known failures have occurred, and likely some unknown ones as well, I don't know how, without technical documentation, one could make sure that one isn't a single not-terribly-improbable failure away from harming somebody.

Comment: @PeteKirkham - The quack part is the part where they cite no studies, rely entirely on personal anecdotes and testimonials, and are direct-marketing a specialized "medical" device to consumers. There is literally no part of their website that **doesn't** scream "quack medical appliance".

Comment: Also, I could find no published research on either [PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=circulation%20booster) or [NICE](https://www.evidence.nhs.uk/search?q=circulation+booster) for their device.

Answer (score 6):

That's not a resistor, that's an inductor, hence the marking *L* 1. Is there any possibility you can see the colours of the rings? They contain a code which indicates the value.

There is a value calculator [here](http://www.electronics2000.co.uk/calc/inductor-code-calculator.php), and a table [here](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/ac_theory/inductors04.php).

If you cannot read the colour code, you could try to find the assembly manual or something like this of the board and look for the L1 code.

But, as Chris Johnson [says](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105185/what-is-this-resistor/105193#comment207935_105185), take care: you cannot *just* replace the component. There might be other damage, and even if not, the cause of the damage should be investigated to make sure it will not happen again.

<sub>On a side note: how I know that this is an inductor, not a resistor? 1) because of the marking *L*, which is used for inductors, *R* is for resistors. 2) it's green, this kind of inductor is often green, resistors are often brown or blue-green. 3) you can see the copper wire inside.</sub>

Comment: It might actually be a choke, a resistor (usually about 10 Ohms) wrapped in an inductor coil. Often found in the power input to circuits.

Comment: @JasonMorgan as far as I know a [choke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_%28electronics%29) is an inductor, I'm not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: @CamilStaps: Most inductors are "intended" to have zero series resistance or parallel capacitance.  Of course, neither resistance nor capacitance will ever actually be zero, but circuits are typically designed to work with any value below the specified maximum.  By contrast, devices marketed as chokes are often deliberately designed not to behave as ideal inductors.  It would make little sense for a coil maker to try to minimize resistance if a circuit designer was going to stick a resistor in series.  If the goal is to have e.g. 10 ohms in series with an ideal inductor...

Comment: ...it's easier to construct a single "not very good" coil, possibly with an integrated resistive element, than it would be to construct a minimal-resistance coil and add a 10-ohm resistor.

Comment: I bought The item for a elderly disabled friend who lived in Spain.
Unfortunately they thought the ac/dc adapter was a normal English plug and replaced it with a Spanish one and plugged it into the mains.
I though that I would replace the inductor in the hope of repairing it but I don't know the specification of this component ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Camil Staps You don't see them as discrete components so often these days, but you still often use the circuit.  Imagine a resistor and inductor in parallel, but instead of using two components, you use one. The insulating body of the resistor becomes the core of the inductor.